# How do special NK cells get to the uterus?

Tags: human-biology

When an embryo is creating a placenta in the uterus, some special kinds of Natural killers cell of the mother will move and gather towards this placenta (for exmaple for growth components increasing blood of the placenta). But how do these NK cells know where to go....do they kind of 'smell' the uterus?

Answer (score 1):

They are attracted via **chemokines**, which are molecules that NK cells sense and move towards the increased chemical gradient.